# Why is it that almost all gods residing on Earth reside on a mountain?

Tags: gods

Almost all religious places in India are located on the peak of a mountain. Why have they chosen that place? Is there any belief underlying that?

Comment: It's not 'all', it's most. For one, Vishnu's address is Kshirsagar, Vaikuntha which is not a mountain rather a sea.

Comment: @VineetMenon thats why i said almost all... not only all...

Comment: Because its believed that Mountain's peaks are nearer to the heavens.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, I too believe so.

Comment: The entire demigod kingdom is atop mount Meru. Surrounding the city of Brahma are the 8 cities of major demigods, as represented in vastu mandala. However on Earth, bodies of water are also used (Shiva has at least one submerged deity, Ganga, other holy rivers, Varuna).

Comment: your question title says all and your question say almost, please correct it.

Answer (score 4):

It is true that many deities have already chosen mountain for meditation,

> Shiva -> Kailas in Himalaya
>
> Dattatreya -> Giranar in Gujarat
>
> GODDESS Kali -> Pavagirh in Gujarat
>
> Balaji -> Thirumala

Many thousands of temples are on mountain.

### Belief, Temple roof can not be walked over

There is one belief or blind faith, I do not know.

that above temple's roof where "Dwaja or flag" is there", It is prohibited that one can not walk on it. Also not on roof.

In our Gujarat also in our homes we never walk on/above the surface where our temple resides. It is strictly prohibited. That's why temples have round shaped roofs. So no body walks on it.

If it is on higher place, obviously people can see it from more distance, so it is good. **But it can not be considered as "proper reason".**

Especially in the case of mountain, we may have better answers.

**Now to find out common reason "Why they are on temple" is very difficult to answer.**

Most temples on mountain are well famous temples.

The main reason behind visiting temple is "Prasad" <- this is not food

> Pra -> Prabhu's
> sa-> Sakhshat
> D -> Darshan

Temples have statues, what else they have? But devotees visit and see this statue and this is Prasad. They can see their deity clearly with eyes.

This "Darshan" is valuable for devotees. Most famous temples are very ancient and chosen by deity. Nobody knows even sometimes who has performed Pran Pratishta ritual of such temples. People have to walk through stairs and do some physical exercise, which is good for their health.

**But this also can not be considered as actual reason why they are on mountain.**

### Real Answer is in the Story

This temples are old temples. So the story behind these temples are the only thing we know about. We can find out reading or hearing story behind these temples.

> **Story behind the temple is the only reason or proof why they are on mountain.**

This may be the right answer.

Comment: `Aiyyappan -> Sabari, Murugan -> Palani`

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Reasons of meditating on mountain**

- Most Gods do meditation and they need cool atmosphere which they can find on mountains.
- Most Gods spend time practicing yogic austerities.
- Normal Humans/animals do not visit mountains regularly.

Also See : [Scientific Advantages of living on mountain](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/mountain-living-more-hear/).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question with respect to Hinduism. If you could cite some scriptural source or teachings of some guru which can be traced back to Hindu sources, it'd make a good answer.

Comment: Kali is one of the 9 vishwaroopam of Parvathi. In that case should her residence be in Kailash rather than Pavagirh?

Comment: Its about kali's temple is in pavagirh where story behind it is the concept.

Comment: Your this answer is the best answer to this question and yet you got a downvote. Your 3rd point says it all "Normal Humans/animals do not visit mountains regularly". Good answers get downvote and bad answers get upvote.